# Group by a value on another row in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I need a new column with the average value of 'SPENDING' from the previous year (for the actual month) of each category of "MAX_ORGAN", not grouped (that is, distributed in the rows). Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
                                            MAX_ORGAN    YEAR   MONTH        SPENDING
1657637                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2017       5          532.35
842540                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       4          285.06
215057                         MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2015       6         1813.25
289674                         MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2015       7         8443.09
2168069                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2017      12          886.00
607522                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015      11         3468.00
172749                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015       5          709.76
907113                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       5          379.50
2377558                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       6          488.00
1016270                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2016       7        10095.08
1452382                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016      12        26511.26
372041                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015       8       227907.11
1553384                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2017       3         6138.80
915397                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       5          900.00
1469685                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2017       2         9536.69
1890718                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2017       9         4980.00
```

It would be like this 'LAST_YEAR_MEAN' column:

```
                                                                       LAST_YEAR_MEAN
607522                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015      11         3468.00               -
172749                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015       5          709.76               -
372041                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2015       8       227907.11               -
842540                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       4          285.06        77361.65
907113                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       5          379.50        77361.65
1452382                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016      12        26511.26        77361.65
915397                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       5          900.00        77361.65
2168069                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2017      12          886.00         7018.95
1553384                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2017       3         6138.80         7018.95
```

A `df.groupby(['MAX_ORGAN', 'YEAR', 'MONTH']).SPENDING.transform('mean')` would work if it weren't for the previous year's issue, so what do you suggest?

In summary:

- I need to put the average value of the previous year in each month for each category in ORGAN.

Answer (score 0):

Changed approach to generate `yrMeanDF` that reflects previous year per month.   Then do a merge on ['MAX_ORGAN', 'YEAR','MONTH'].   If you want 'whole previous year' then remove `MONTH` on creating yrMeanDF and on merge.

```
    import datetime
    curYR = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y')
    curYR = '2017'
    cols = ['MAX_ORGAN', 'YEAR','MONTH']
    # Normalize month too 2 digits
    df.MONTH = df.MONTH.apply(lambda v : '%02d'%int(v))
    # Transform YEAR to numeric
    df.YEAR = df.YEAR.astype(int)
    # Create lookup of previous years.   NOTE that year is decreased to match on merge
    yrMeanDF = df.groupby(cols).SPENDING.mean().reset_index()
    yrMeanDF.rename(columns=dict(SPENDING = 'PREV'), inplace=True)
    yrMeanDF.YEAR -= 1
    # Merge on organ, year, month... if prev not found it gets NaN
    df2 = df.merge(yrMeanDF, how='left',on=['MAX_ORGAN','YEAR','MONTH'])
    df3 = df2.groupby(cols).PREV.mean().reset_index()
    print(df3)
```

output

```
                 MAX_ORGAN  YEAR MONTH      PREV
0     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2015    05    639.75
1     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2015    08       NaN
2     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2015    11       NaN
3     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2016    04       NaN
4     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2016    05       NaN
5     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2016    12    886.00
6     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2017    03       NaN
7     MINISTERIO DA DEFESA  2017    12       NaN
8   MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2015    06       NaN
9   MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2015    07  10095.08
10  MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2016    07       NaN
11  MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2017    02       NaN
12  MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2017    05       NaN
13  MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2017    09       NaN
14  MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO  2018    06       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, Frank. But it's important not to group/stack anything because it's a 3 million rows dataset for machine learning and I will do this same procedure for a bunch of columns. I edited the post to summary the question: I need to put the average value of the previous year in each month for each category in MAX_ORGAN.

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way:

```
df['ID_ANO_REF'] = df['ID_ANO']+1 

for x in range(10):
    col = df.columns[x]
    dft = df.groupby([col, 'YEAR_REF', 'MONTH'])['SPENDING'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'SPENDING' : f'LAST_YEAR_MEAN_{col}'}).rename(columns={'YEAR_REF': 'YEAR'})
    dfn = pd.merge(df, dft, how='left', left_on=[col, 'YEAR', 'MONTH'], right_on=[col, 'YEAR', 'MONTH'], left_index=False, right_index=False)
```

The result:

```
                                     NO_ORGAO_MAXI_UO  ID_ANO  ID_MES  DESPESAS_PAGAS  MED_REF_ID_ORGAO_MAXI_UO
326550          MINISTERIO DO DESENVOLVIMENTO AGRARIO    2015       8        476.2100               nan
2425471                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       6      31334.6100        38651.4968
1647142                   MINISTERIO DO MEIO AMBIENTE    2017       5       8302.2400        31366.1366
2570900                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       8       4779.7300        41265.9815
982398                           MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       6        779.2200        32240.1416
1823472                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2017       7       2922.4100        27739.7249
2021856                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2017      11      31368.4000        58441.4860
2632813                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       8       3733.1500        41265.9815
2613457                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       8      33583.8000        41265.9815
1140810                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2016       8       1576.0500        29890.0638
2934449                          MINISTERIO DA DEFESA    2018      12       1674.0000        39665.7622
2110684     MINISTERIO DA JUSTICA E SEGURANCA PUBLICA    2017      11         -0.9800        48679.1007
960727                            MINISTERIO DA SAUDE    2016       6      39414.9800       240441.2055
2278429                        MINISTERIO DA EDUCACAO    2018       3       4680.0000        38669.8653
```